# cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

On my xcode project I have a `view` with a `tableview`. I also have a "special" string that contains the objects to populate the array that populates the tableview.
Example:

```
NSString *myValues=[[NSString alloc]init]; 
myValues = @"aaa$bbb$ccc?111$222$333?";
```

as you can see the characters $ and ? separate the objects.
When I call the view I populate the array by the string but the tableview doesn't work. Here some code:

File.H:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EquipaggioVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    UITableView *tableViewEquipaggio;
    UITableViewCell *nibLoadedCell;

    NSMutableArray *arrayEquipaggio;

    NSString *stringaDati;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewEquipaggio;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *nibLoadedCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayEquipaggio;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringaDati;

@end
```

File.M:

```
#import "EquipaggioVC.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ClassEquipaggio.h"
@interface EquipaggioVC ()

@end

@implementation EquipaggioVC
@synthesize tableViewEquipaggio;
@synthesize nibLoadedCell;
@synthesize arrayEquipaggio;
@synthesize stringaDati;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)uuid
{
    //to create an ID
    CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef uuidStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidRef);
    CFRelease(uuidRef);
    return [(NSString *)uuidStringRef autorelease];
}
-(void)loadTestData:(NSString*)stringaDatiArray{

//populate the array by the string.
    if(stringaDatiArray!=nil){
        NSArray *elenco=[stringaDatiArray componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];

        for (int i=0; i<([elenco count]-1) ; i++) {

            NSString *dettagliEquipaggio=[[NSString alloc]init];

            dettagliEquipaggio=[elenco objectAtIndex:i];
            NSArray *dettagli=[dettagliEquipaggio componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];
            ClassEquipaggio *aEquipaggio=[[ClassEquipaggio alloc]init];
            aEquipaggio.idMembro=[dettagli objectAtIndex:0];
            aEquipaggio.sessoMembro=[dettagli objectAtIndex:1];
            aEquipaggio.dataNascitaMembro=[dettagli objectAtIndex:2];

            [arrayEquipaggio addObject:aEquipaggio];
            [aEquipaggio release];

        }
    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableEquipaggioView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *sLoadNibNamed;
    UITableViewCell *cell;


    ClassEquipaggio *aEquipaggio=[arrayEquipaggio objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell = [tableEquipaggioView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    sLoadNibNamed=@"EquipaggioCell";


    if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:sLoadNibNamed owner:self options:NULL];
        cell = [self typeNibLoadCell:aEquipaggio.idMembro];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    UILabel *tipoSessoLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    tipoSessoLabel.text = aEquipaggio.sessoMembro;

    UILabel *dataNascitaLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    dataNascitaLabel.text=aEquipaggio.dataNascitaMembro;

    return cell;
}




-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [arrayEquipaggio count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)typeNibLoadCell:(NSString *)named{
    return nibLoadedCell;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrayEquipaggio=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    stringaDati=[[NSString alloc]init];
    tableViewEquipaggio=[[UITableView alloc]init];

}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    UIBarButtonItem * btnIndietroa = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Indietro"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                      target:self
                                                                      action:@selector(editNavButtonPressed)]autorelease];

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:btnIndietroa];
    stringaDati = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringaDati"];

    if(stringaDati!=nil){

        [arrayEquipaggio removeAllObjects];
        [self loadTestData:stringaDati];
    }

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

On nib file the tableview has the connection with the `delegate` and `datasource`, as the IBoutlet is connected with it.

Thanks for your support.

EDIT: `[arrayEquipaggio count]` return 0.

Comment: Please check the value of `[arrayEquipaggio count]`   I mean the row count.

Comment: Two questions: have you tried defining the string like this << myValues = @"aaa$bbb$ccc?111$222$333?"; >>. I think you missed the @"" defining it. And second one: what numberOfRowsInSection returns?

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt work..?

Comment: What do you mean with 'It doesn't work'? Does the tableView not call it's datasource methods, or is the array maybe empty?

Comment: @MarcoPace the string is correct, my bad now I edit the question ;)

Comment: @Marcel the "CellForRowAtIndexPath" is not called. On debug I put a breakpoint but the debugger doesn't go there

Comment: Put a break point in `numberOfRowsInSection:` and check for row count. If the row count is 0 then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not get called.

Comment: so your problem is that you haven't setted up the delegate properly. Can you try dong it programmatically?

Comment: ok, [arrayEquipaggio count] -> 0 values.

Comment: for a tableView you have to set it's datasource delegate object. Also, check if numberOfSectionsInTableView: is called.

Comment: it seems that it all depends on stringaDati variable on the viewDidAppear method, check the value on that variable to see if the loadTestData method is being called

Comment: `[arrayEquipaggio count]` needs to return a number greater than `0`. If it return `0` it means that there is no data to pupulate your table's rows

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your question your problem is that the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not being called and as you said the `[arrayEquipaggio count]` return `0`.

Since you are using that array at the method `numberOfRowsInSection` with a return value of `0`  is normal that your table is not calling the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Since you are telling to your table that there are no rows.

If you want your table to be populated then check that your array return a value greater than `0`.

In a nutshell It has no data to populate your table, that why it doesnt work.

Check that in your `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` that your are pulling anything to `stringaDati`.

```
NSLog(@"info: %@",stringaDati);
```